# Why am I getting InsecurePlatformWarning on mac?

Tags: python, pip

when I ran `pip freeze` I got the following warning:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:79: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
InsecurePlatformWarning
```

When I follow the url to [here](https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning), it seems to suggest could ignore it.  Is that right?  Is this something I need to address?

Comment: `sudo pip install requests[security]`

Comment: hi @PadraicCunningham !  Thanks again for chiming in again.  Are you suggesting I should run that command?

Comment: yes, if you run into errors you may have to install some ssl  deps.

Comment: no prob, you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

do as followed:

```
brew install openssl
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2c/include/openssl /usr/local/include/openssl
pip install --upgrade urllib3
pip install pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1
```